# Analyzing a list of terms and their nearest neighbors in Postgres 11.5

Tags: postgresql, join, knn, fuzzy-comparison

I've got a database where we regularly need to do fuzzy/distance matching on strings. In this example, the target `citext` field is named `analytic_scan.inv_name`. But the same sort of code could be useful for any number of other `text` and `citext` fields. The rest of the table structure doesn't come into play for this query.

Starting from a [tip about K-NN text searches](https://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks) from Tom Lane, I've got a [trigram](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) GIST index, which implements the `<->` distance operator. Using the tip, a query for the 10 closest neighbors to a string looks like this:

```
select distinct on (inv_name <-> 'Pack CT - 002') inv_name,
       inv_name <-> 'Pack CT - 002' AS distance

    from analytic_scan

order by 2 -- order by the distance column...using the column position saves retyping the formula here.

  limit 10;
```

This works fine, although with 7M+ rows, it takes some time. My goals are to calculate and store a set of values for quick lookups, like this:

- Find the distinct terms in the target field, `analytic_scan.inv_name`.
- For each term, calculate the frequency of the term, and the frequency percentile.
- For each term, find the 10 (or 100, etc.) closest neighbors and their distance.

From there, I'll want to add the `distance_min`, `distance_max`, and `distance_width` for each term, which I'm figuring that I can do with the right window function magic. (I'm not trying that part here.)

The K-NN search is above, the frequency count search is pretty simple:

```
  select distinct inv_name,
         count(*) as frequency,
         ntile(100) OVER(ORDER BY count(*)) as frequency_percentile

    from analytic_scan

group by inv_name

order by 1,2;
```

Combining the two queries is what has me stumped. It feels like a `LATERAL JOIN`, but I could well be wrong about that. I've experimented some, but this is not giving me any values in the columns from the KNN subquery, they're all `NULL`. Also, I'm getting one row per term, not 10. So, clearly, I'm going this wrong.

To be clear, I *do* get the expected columns:

```
inv_name
frequency
frequency_percentile
neighbor_name
distance
```

...but the KNN-based fields are not populated, and I'm only getting one row of output rather than the 10 set in the `LIMIT 10` clause of the KNN search. I know that what I want is to apply the "find 10 neighbors" code to each of the items in my sample, and don't know how to do that properly. I'm tyring `LATERAL`, but if there's a better way, I'm all for it.

```
-- Final results I'm after, with one row per *neighbor*. 
-- So, 10x the distinct terms, in this case.
select frequency_table.inv_name,
       frequency_table.frequency,
       frequency_table.frequency_percentile,
       knn.neighbor_name,
       knn.distance

 -- Calculate the distinct terms and their frequencies. There are 6,958 distinct terms in my sample table.  
  from (
            select inv_name,
                   count(*) as frequency,
                   ntile(100) OVER(ORDER BY count(*)) as frequency_percentile

               from analytic_scan 

            group by inv_name
    ) frequency_table

-- I'm wanting to "multiply" the terms above with the 10 neighbors below. LEFT JOIN is obviously wrong. 
   left join lateral -- CROSS JOIN LATERAL gives me 70 rows on 6,958 distinct terms. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

 -- Find the 10 nearest neighbors.     
   (select distinct on (analytic_scan.inv_name <-> frequency_table.inv_name) analytic_scan.inv_name AS neighbor_name,
           analytic_scan.inv_name <-> frequency_table.inv_name AS distance

      from analytic_scan
     where frequency_table.inv_name = analytic_scan.inv_name and
           frequency_table.frequency_percentile = 1

     limit 10

      ) knn ON TRUE

   order by frequency_table.inv_name,
            knn.distance
```

If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great. I'm clearly out over my skis here.

Note: I'll likely end up storing one row per term with either an array or a `jsonb` with the neighbor data. For the moment, the data will be used by a client app, and they just want a JSON array. Normally, I'm allergic to packed fields, but it likely makes sense in this case. I'm not attempting the consolidation here as I figured it makes sense to get the basic query right. But if someone has a solution that ends up creating a JSON aggregation instead of my one-row-per-neighbor, that's fine too. Here's the sort of table I'm imagining:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS analytics.inv_name_frequency (
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT extensions.gen_random_uuid(),   -- What the boss likes.
    inv_name         citext    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    frequency        integer   NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    frequency_range  int4range NOT NULL DEFAULT '(0,0)'::int4range    -- For min, max distances.
    frequency_width  integer   NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,           -- Stores min-max value, can use a calculated column in PG12.
    neighbors        jsonb     NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb) -- JSON array with {"term","foo","distance":0.3} for each neighbor.
```

## Follow-up details

jjanes, whose comments and code I've used a lot out of the SO archives, took the time to reply. My answer won't fit in a comment, so I'm adding it here. It might help to clarify that *yes*, the data I'm looking at is messy. The first thing we do is to help people to move from non-standard and inconsistent names to a set of highly standardized names. That takes a bunch of software, and just as much human skill and effort. Honestly, we should hire anthropologists because the bulk of the work is extracting local knowledge. The starting point for the standardization process is years of accumulated, real-world data with all kinds of inconsistencies. That's the data I'm looking at here.

We've attacked automated matching with a lot of fuzzy string comparison, and I really love the Postgres implementation of trigrams. When I read the "K-NN" search tip, it looked like a pretty interesting way to find patterns in the "soup" tables of historical data. It's reasonably fast, for what it's doing....even as I've written the code. With a fistful of near terms captured quickly and/or stored for retrieval, then you have a really good starting point for doing more expensive similarity scoring with Levenshtein, etc.

So, as an experiment, I'd like to build up a table of terms and near neighbors on the historical data. I can do this easily in a client language, even PL/PgSQL

- `select distinct` with Postgres
- Iterate over each results, get the neighbors, store the results.

But this seems like something that should be possible in straight SQL in Postgres, and I'd like to figure out how. There are *many* times I'd like to do extended frequency analysis on text. As the comments on my code show, it's pretty clear that my mental map for what's going on during the queries is....pretty blank. I'd like to develop a better understanding of how to do a `lateral join` or subqueries, etc. to solve this problem with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

LATERAL join does seem to be just what you want, but your implementation of it is weird:

> ```
> analytic_scan.inv_name <-> frequency_table.inv_name AS distance
> ...
> where frequency_table.inv_name = analytic_scan.inv_name
> ```

It certainly doesn't make sense to pull in all the similars, then remove everything that is not identical.

> ```
>    frequency_table.frequency_percentile = 1
> ```

This also doesn't seem to have any sense to it.  If you really want to filter on this (and doing seems to contradict your prose description), why would you do it here?  This clause seems to correlate to nothing I find in your description of what you are trying to do.  You don't populated columns for anything but the first row of frequency_table, because you went out of your way to remove those results.

You "knn" lateral query seems to have a WHERE clause it does not need, and be missing an ORDER BY that it does need.

Also, your table analytic_scan is probably misdesigned.  If you want to find similar names, you probably want a table of deduplicated names.  Then you wouldn't need the DISTINCT ON, which is likely to cause problems with index use.

Comment: I updated my question to provide a bit of clarification on what I'm doing, and what I'm trying to do.